# How to maintain scroll position on back button press in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I would like the window.scrollTop position of Route/pages to be stored along with the URL so that when I press the back button in my browser, the page can be scrolled to the position it was left in. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The addon 'memory-scroll' should help with that: https://emberobserver.com/addons/memory-scroll

especially the 'remember-document-scroll' component.